# Best way to use apache and python on an embedded platform with debian linux

Tags: apache, python-2.7, debian

We are programming an embedded system on debian linux in python 2.7.  We need an on-board web server and since I'm fairly new to this environment, I'm confused by all the options and would like some advice.  Our main application is in python and when a user accesses the web server they will need to see and modify information that is contained inside that main app.  Should I be using mod_python, cgi, mod_wsgi, or something else?  How do I get the Apache python instance to communicate with the main instance?

What is the best way to do this and where can I find setup help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be using Apache and Python i'd suggest you'd use the python microframework [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Apache seems a bit heavy to use for an embedded device, i'd suggest something like Lighttpd or Nginx, not as resource hungry as Apache.

But if you want something that's easy to set up i'd stick with Apache & Flask over mod_wsgi, as flask is 100% WSGI 1.0 compliant.